# Factor analysis: regression equation and residuals

Tags: spss, factor-analysis

I have used factor analysis with regression method. I was trying to develop an index using this regression equation by using the output of the component score coefficient matrix (SPSS) generated for each factor. Should I include the residuals found under the "Reproduced Correlations Table" (SPSS) in the regression equation?